# Object has no attribute 'root'

Tags: python, kivy

I am following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceMVwnKCtOU and almost copied his code, but I´ve remade it a bit but I get this error:

> File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\stopwatch_timer\main.py", line 15, in stopwatch
> self.root.ids.counter.text = str(int(self.root.ids.counter.text) + 1)
> AttributeError: 'Stopwatch' object has no attribute 'root'

My main file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Stopwatch(BoxLayout):

    def start_stopwatch(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.stopwatch, 1)

    def stopwatch(self, *args):
        self.root.ids.counter.text = str(int(self.root.ids.counter.text) + 1)
        

class TimerApp(App):
    pass

TimerApp().run()
```

My kivy file:

```
Stopwatch:

<Stopwatch>:
    Button:
        text: "Start Stopwatch"
        on_press: root.start_stopwatch()
    Label:
        id: counter
        text: "0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you said `almost copied` but code in video is different - code is in `MainApp` but you didn't put  your code in `TimeApp` but in `Stopwatch` - and this can make all problem.

Comment: if I use `self.ids` instead of `self.root.ids` then code works.

Answer (score 0):

You said `"almost copied"` but code in video is different.

You have code in `Stopwatch` but video has in `MainApp` - and this makes all problem.

`MainApp` needs `self.root` to access elements in `GridLayout` but `GridLayout` would need only `self` to access elements in `GridLayout`

The same with your code: `TimerApp` would need `self.root` to access elements in `Stopwatch` but `Stopwatch` needs only `self` to access elements in `Stopwatch`

---

If you use `self.ids` instead of `self.root.ids` then it will work

```
class Stopwatch(BoxLayout):

    def start_stopwatch(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_watch, 1)

    def update_watch(self, *args):
        self.ids.counter.text = str(int(self.ids.counter.text) + 1)

class TimerApp(App):
    pass
```

---

**BTW:**

If you would move `Clock.schedule_interval` to `TimerApp` then it would need `self.root.stopwatch` instead of `self.stopwatch` to run `Stopwatch.stopwatch`

```
class Stopwatch(BoxLayout):

    def update_watch(self, *args):
        self.ids.counter.text = str(int(self.ids.counter.text) + 1)

class TimerApp(App):

    def start_stopwatch(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.update_watch, 1)
```

and `timer.kv` would need `app` instead of `root`

```
on_press: app.start_stopwatch()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full version with `self.root`

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Stopwatch(BoxLayout):

    def update_watch(self, *args):
        self.ids.counter.text = str(int(self.ids.counter.text) + 1)
        
class TimerApp(App):
    
    job = None  # to keep access to running Clock
    
    def start_stop_watch(self, *args):
        if not self.job:
            self.root.ids.counter.text = "0"
            self.job = Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.update_watch, 1)
            self.root.ids.button.text = "Stop"
        else:
            self.job.cancel()  # stop clock
            self.job = None    # to use again in `if not self.job:`
            self.root.ids.button.text = "Start"

TimerApp().run()
```

**timer.kv**

```
Stopwatch:

<Stopwatch>:
    Button:
        id: button
        text: "Start"
        on_press: app.start_stop_watch()
    Label:
        id: counter
        text: "0"
```

---

Full version without `self.root`

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Stopwatch(BoxLayout):

    job = None
    
    def start_stop_watch(self, *args):
        if not self.job:
            self.ids.counter.text = "0"
            self.job = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_watch, 1)
            self.ids.button.text = "Stop"
        else:
            self.job.cancel()
            self.job = None
            self.ids.button.text = "Start"

    def update_watch(self, *args):
        self.ids.counter.text = str(int(self.ids.counter.text) + 1)
        
class TimerApp(App):
    pass    

TimerApp().run()
```

**timer.kv**

```
Stopwatch:

<Stopwatch>:
    Button:
        id: button
        text: "Start"
        on_press: root.start_stop_watch()
    Label:
        id: counter
        text: "0"
```

---

Full version with all code in `TimerApp`

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Stopwatch(BoxLayout):
    pass
    
class TimerApp(App):
    
    job = None
    
    def start_stop_watch(self, *args):
        if not self.job:
            self.root.ids.counter.text = "0"
            self.job = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_watch, 1)  # without `root`
            self.root.ids.button.text = "Stop"
        else:
            self.job.cancel()
            self.job = None
            self.root.ids.button.text = "Start"

    def update_watch(self, *args):
        self.root.ids.counter.text = str(int(self.root.ids.counter.text) + 1)

TimerApp().run()
```

**timer.kv**

```
Stopwatch:

<Stopwatch>:
    Button:
        id: button
        text: "Start"
        on_press: app.start_stop_watch()
    Label:
        id: counter
        text: "0"
```